# Kotlin field Assignment via Scope Function (Apply )

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between two such field assignments? Actually, the first way seems very readable but I come across second way in many code samples.

Is there a special reason?

```
class Login {

    var grantToken = GrantTokenRequest()
 
    fun schema(schema: String) {
        this.grantToken.schema = schema
    }
    
}




class Login {

    var grantToken = GrantTokenRequest()

    fun schema(schema: String) = apply { this.grantToken.schema = schema }
   

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the return type of the function `schema`.

The first way returns `Unit`.

The second way returns the type of what `this` is in the current scope.
In your case the second way will return the `Login` type, so the instance of this class.

The second approach is just more idiomatic in cases when you are "configuring an object". From [Kotlin docs about apply](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply)

> The common case for apply is the object configuration. Such calls can be read as “apply the following assignments to the object [and return the object itself].”

One reason why the second approach is useful, is because it makes call chaining possible. The general term for this kind of "return this" method chaining is ["fluent interface"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

```
val login = Login()
    .schema("...")
    .anotherFunctionOnLoginClass(...)
    .moreCallChaining(...)
```

An additional note: The `this` used inside the `apply` lambda is not needed, because apply already sets `this` as the [Receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply). The code could be simplified to

```
fun schema(schema: String) = apply { grantToken.schema = schema }
```

Comment: The general term for this kind of "return `this`" method chaining is ["fluent interface"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thanks, added in the answer as well.

Comment: Though there's much less need for ‘fluent’ interfaces in Kotlin than in many other languages, since scoping functions such as `apply()` (when used as intended!) can give most of the benefits without polluting the API.